# I'm struggling to test this redux saga

Tags: testing, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm relatively new to redux-saga and struggling to test this code:

```
import { normalize } from 'normalizr';

export function* normalizeResponse(denormalized, schema) {
  const normalized = yield call(normalize, denormalized, schema);
  return normalized;
}

export function* request(apiFn, action, schema) {
  try {
    yield put(requestStart({ type: action.type }));
    const denormalized = yield call(apiFn, action.payload, action.meta);
    const normalized = yield call(normalizeResponse, denormalized, schema);
    yield put(requestSuccess({ type: action.type }));
    return normalized;
  } catch (e) {
    if (__DEV__ && !__TEST__) {
      Alert.alert('Something went wrong');
      console.log(`Error in request saga: ${action.type}`, e);
    }
    if (action.type) {
      const payload = { type: action.type, error: e };
      const meta = action.payload || {};
      yield put(requestFailure(payload, meta));
    }
  }
}

export function* photosShow() {
  while (true) {
    const action = yield take(t.PHOTOS_SHOW);
    const normalized = yield call(request, api.show, action, {
      photo: schema.photo,
    });
    if (normalized) yield put(setEntities(normalized));
  }
}
```

Online, I've found a number of redux saga test packages and some tutorials but none of them seems to cover much more than the basics. Here is the step-by-step of how the saga works:

- `photosShow` is called with a Flux standard action, with payload of { id: 1}
- This will call the generator `request` which is a utility function to make an API request and then normalise the response.
- Firstly, a `requestStart` action will be triggered
- Then the api endpoint will be called
- If successful, a requestSuccess action will be triggered
- The response will be then be normalised using normalizr
- And then stored in the redux state with `setEntities` (back in photosShow)

Any help moving forward with how to go about this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Alex? Have you read my answer? 

Answer (score 0):

I struggled reading all the `redux-saga` testing resources too... without finding a suitable solution (at least, for me).

What I ended up is:

- I "render" an empty React app with a working store
- I manually trigger the interesting actions (the ones that trigger the sagas I'm testing)
- I spy every external resource consumed by the sagas

In the end: I trigger the sagas, and I spy that they trigger other stuff.

I consider the sagas a black-box, and I check that they respect the contract with all the other parts of the app.

I take an example from my authentication sagas tests (I broke a lot of testing good practices, I know, it comes from my early testing days with saga) (see below for the `renderWithRedux` and `spyUtil` functions):

```
describe("Login flow with valid credentials", () => {
  let user = "stefano";
  let pwd = "my_super_secret_password";
  let app;
  let spies;
  // const spiedConsole = spyConsole();
  beforeAll(() => {
    app = renderWithRedux(<></>);
    spies = {
      LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator: spyUtil(authActions, "LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator"),
      navigate: spyUtil(ReachRouter, "navigate"),
      postLogin: spyUtil(authNetwork, "postLogin", postLoginOk),
      redirectBackFromLoginPage: spyUtil(navigationData, "redirectBackFromLoginPage")
    };
  });
  test("1 - the login API should be called as soon as the LOGIN_REQUEST action is dispatched", async () => {
    app.store.dispatch(authActions.LOGIN_REQUEST_creator(user, pwd));
    expect(spies.postLogin.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user, pwd);
  });
  test("2 - then when the login API is successfull, a LOGIN_SUCCESS action should be dispatched with the tokens", async () => {
    expect(spies.LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.any(String),
      expect.any(String)
    );
  });
  test("3 - then the router should be asked to make a redirect to the initial location", async () => {
    expect(spies.redirectBackFromLoginPage.spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spies.navigate.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringMatching(/\//));
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    spies.values().forEach(obj => obj.spy.mockRestore());
    // spiedConsole.mockRestore();
    cleanup();
  });
});
```

Step by step:
- I render an empty app with a working Redux+Saga store

```
app = renderWithRedux(<></>);
```

- I spy everything outside the sagas

```
spies = {
      LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator: spyUtil(authActions, "LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator"),
      navigate: spyUtil(ReachRouter, "navigate"),
      postLogin: spyUtil(authNetwork, "postLogin", postLoginOk),
      redirectBackFromLoginPage: spyUtil(navigationData, "redirectBackFromLoginPage")
    };
```

where:

- `LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator` is an action creator
- `navigate` comes from Reach Router
- `postLogin` makes the AJAX request (mocking it with a fake function returning a "success" response almost immediately (but resolving a promise))
- `redirectBackFromLoginPage` is a function that consume again (with some conditions) the `navigate` utility

  - I trigger the `LOGIN_REQUEST` action, and I expect that the AJAX trigger function has been called with the right credentials

```
test("1 - the login API should be called as soon as the LOGIN_REQUEST action is dispatched", async () => {
  app.store.dispatch(authActions.LOGIN_REQUEST_creator(user, pwd));
  expect(spies.postLogin.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(user, pwd);
});
```

- I check that the `LOGIN_SUCCESS` action will be dispatched with the auth tokens

```
test("2 - then when the login API is successfull, a LOGIN_SUCCESS action should be dispatched with the tokens", async () => {
  expect(spies.LOGIN_SUCCESS_creator.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
    expect.any(String),
    expect.any(String)
  );
});
```

- I check that the router has been called with the right route (`/` for the home page)

```
test("3 - then the router should be asked to make a redirect to the initial location", async () => {
  expect(spies.redirectBackFromLoginPage.spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(spies.navigate.spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.stringMatching(/\//));
});
```

- then, I clear everything

```
afterAll(() => {
  spies.values().forEach(obj => obj.spy.mockRestore());
  // spiedConsole.mockRestore();
  cleanup();
});
```

This is "my" (it comes from Kent C. Dodds) `renderWithRedux` function

```
// @see https://github.com/kentcdodds/react-testing-library/blob/master/examples/__tests__/react-redux.js
export function renderWithRedux(ui, { initialState, store = configureStore() } = {}) {
  return {
    ...render(
      <div>
        <Provider store={store}>{ui}</Provider>
      </div>
    ),
    // adding `store` to the returned utilities to allow us
    // to reference it in our tests (just try to avoid using
    // this to test implementation details).
    store
  };
}
```

where `configureStore` is a function of mine that build the whole Redux store with the various middlewares.

This is my `spyUtil` function

```
/**
 * A all-in-one spy and mock function
 * @param {object} obj
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {function} mockFunction
 */
export function spyUtil(obj, name, mockFunction = undefined) {
  const spy = jest.spyOn(obj, name);
  let mock;
  if (mockFunction) {
    mock = jest.fn(mockFunction);
    obj[name].mockImplementation(mock);
  }
  return { spy, mock };
}
```

Please note that's just one of the authentication flows, I haven't reported here all the cases.

I'd like to know your thoughts about it